# What is the difference between an ArrayItems vs SingleItems in Jackson JsonSchema module?

Tags: json, scala, jackson, jsonschema, jackson-modules

In the documentation, [`ArrayItems`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jsonSchema/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jsonSchema/types/ArraySchema.ArrayItems.html) is described as

> When this attribute value is an array of jsonSchemas and the instance value is an array, each position in the instance array MUST conform to the jsonSchema in the corresponding position for this array

and [`SingleItems`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jsonSchema/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jsonSchema/types/ArraySchema.SingleItems.html) as

> When this attribute value is a jsonSchema and the instance value is an array, then all the items in the array MUST be valid according to the jsonSchema.

but  I don't really understand what the `attribute value` and `instance` is referring to. If I just want to know the data types of items in the array, which one should I use?